# Limit the background threads to less than five Every time

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I want to limit the background thread to less than five every time.  I have to call file upload API concurrently very time I select some files from the gallery. I have to call the same API multiple times i.e if I picked 4 images I have to call the same API Four times concurrently in the background thread.  If the image count is greater than 5 then I have to Pick first five Images and make five API requests, if anyone of five requests gives the response then pick one more image and add to the background thread.

The same process should be done until all 20 image API requests give the response. I am using Alamofire for multipart upload and MVVM design Pattern.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
if imagepresent{
    for i in 0..<imgparameters.count {
        do {
            let documentData = try Data(contentsOf: imgparameters[i]["fileUrl"] as! URL, options: .dataReadingMapped)

            multipartFormData.append(documentData, withName: "attachments", fileName: "\(imgparameters[i]["fileName"] ?? "\(datestr)\(i).jpg")", mimeType: "\(imgparameters[i]["type"] ?? "image/jpg")")

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
for (key, value) in parameters {
    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
}}, to:requestURL,method : methodType,headers : headerss)

{ (result) in

switch result {

case .success(let upload, _, let streamFileURL):

    self.uploadRequest = upload

    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in

    })
    upload.responseJSON { response in

        self.uploadRequest = nil

        if (response.error == nil)

        {
            self.saveCookies(response: response)
        }

        self.handleResponse(response: response, completionBlockX: completionBlock
    }
case .failure(let encodingError):
    print(encodingError)
 }
}
```

Thanks for quick answers.

Comment: You could wrap the upload calls into GCD queues and limit them by using a `DispatchSemaphore`, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore

Comment: @AndreasOetjen should I wrap all 20 upload calls into GCD Same time.

Comment: You can also use NSOperationQueue and limit concurrent operations https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue?language=objc

Comment: @AliBaqbani can you give some code to achieve this

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/parallel-programming-with-swift-operations-54cbefaf3cb0